# Facebook page's photo album in page tab

Tags: facebook

How can I add my page's photo album to tab?

As we all know default is that we have Photos in tab and after clicking it we can go to albums.

What I want is to have Albums directly on tab and by clicking it to go to Albums.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with the standard Facebook functionality IMHO. It's possible that there are some third party apps which can do this...